# Trouble hiding and showing widgets in response to event

Tags: c, xml, user-interface, gtk3

## Problem

I have a problem where closing a widget with the delete event, via gtk_widget_hide_on_delete fails to show the menu widget again via a swapped gtk_widget_show_all with the corresponding widget passed to it as an argument.

## Background

I'm creating a program consisting of a selection menu with a number of button widgets. Pressing one button will hide the menu, and show a window widget containing a label and a TextEntry, the delete event of this window widget will hide the widget, and show the menu again.

## Example program

I've created a minimal example for this problem. The code simply loads the ui via `GtkBuilder` and then enters the main gtk loop.

I rely on `gtk_widget_show_all`, `gtk_widget_hide` and `gtk_widget_hide_on_delete`, but when I close the *exercise widget* using the `delete-event`, the window disappears, but the menu widget isn't shown.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    GtkBuilder * builder;
    GtkWidget * menu;
    GError *error = NULL;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    builder = gtk_builder_new();
    if (!gtk_builder_add_from_file(builder, "example.glade", &error)) {
        g_warning("%s", error->message);
        g_free(error);
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load build file");
    }

    menu = (GtkWidget *) gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "menu");
  
    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);
    gtk_widget_show(menu);

    gtk_main();
  
    return 0;
}
```

The XML file example.glade has been created using Glade.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.16.1 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.10"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="exercise">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="window_position">center</property>
    <signal name="delete-event" handler="gtk_widget_hide_on_delete" swapped="no"/>
    <signal name="delete-event" handler="gtk_widget_show_all" object="menu" after="yes" swapped="yes"/>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkGrid" id="grid2">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkEntry" id="entry1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="hexpand">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="left_attach">0</property>
            <property name="top_attach">1</property>
            <property name="width">1</property>
            <property name="height">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLabel" id="label1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="hexpand">True</property>
            <property name="vexpand">True</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">A window where stuff will happen.</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="left_attach">0</property>
            <property name="top_attach">0</property>
            <property name="width">1</property>
            <property name="height">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="menu">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="window_position">center</property>
    <signal name="destroy" handler="gtk_main_quit" swapped="no"/>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkGrid" id="grid1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="button1">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">button1</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
            <property name="hexpand">True</property>
            <property name="vexpand">True</property>
            <signal name="clicked" handler="gtk_widget_hide" object="menu" swapped="yes"/>
            <signal name="clicked" handler="gtk_widget_show_all" object="exercise" swapped="yes"/>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="left_attach">0</property>
            <property name="top_attach">0</property>
            <property name="width">1</property>
            <property name="height">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="button2">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">button2</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
            <property name="hexpand">True</property>
            <property name="vexpand">True</property>
            <signal name="clicked" handler="gtk_widget_hide" object="menu" swapped="yes"/>
            <signal name="clicked" handler="gtk_widget_show_all" object="exercise" swapped="yes"/>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="left_attach">0</property>
            <property name="top_attach">1</property>
            <property name="width">1</property>
            <property name="height">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in these two lines of your Glade file:

```xml
<signal name="delete-event" handler="gtk_widget_hide_on_delete" swapped="no"/>
<signal name="delete-event" handler="gtk_widget_show_all" object="menu" after="yes" swapped="yes"/>
```

Looking at the [manual page](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-hide-on-delete) of `gtk_widget_hide_on_delete()`, we see:

> Utility function; intended to be connected to the “delete-event” signal on a GtkWindow. The function calls `gtk_widget_hide()` on its argument, then returns `TRUE`.

If we look at the [delete-event](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-delete-event) signal, we see:

> #### Returns
>
> `TRUE` to stop other handlers from being invoked for the event. `FALSE` to propagate the event further.

This means that after the `gtk_widget_hide_on_delete()` is called, `TRUE` is returned, and this stops the GTK runtime from calling `gtk_widget_show_all()`.

To achieve what you want, you can use a custom-defined handler, as shown below:

1. Remove that two lines and replace with the following:

   ```xml
   <signal name="delete-event" handler="my_custom_func" object="menu" swapped="no"/>
   ```
2. Add your custom handler to the C file:

   ```c
   G_MODULE_EXPORT gboolean
   my_custom_func(GtkWidget *w, GdkEvent *e, gpointer u) {
       gtk_widget_hide(w);
       gtk_widget_show_all(GTK_WIDGET(u));
       return TRUE;
   }
   ```

Comment: @LeonhardPrintz You can mark this answer as "accepted" by clicking on the green check mark on the left of this post.

Comment: Btw, how do I get syntax highlighting when posting code? (for the next time I post a question) I want it to be as readable as possible, and this was my first post so I likely made it a bit longer than needed.